# WinObjC: How to know what cocoa frameworks are supported / handled?

Tags: ios, objective-c, winobjc

Trying to bridge my iOS application to W10 app using WinObjC which looks nice (but still a preview)

My iOS app is using CommonCryptor for encryption purpose. When I try to build my freshly imported app in Visual Studio I got an error related to kCCKeySizeAES128 which is missing (coming from CommonCrypto).

How can I assume that this native framework is supported by WinObjC, and if it is supported how can I tell that everything is working (link is done right in visual studio) / where do I look?

Answer (score 2):

I work on the iOS bridge project at Microsoft. While we've implemented many of the iOS frameworks commonly used by apps, we haven't done them all; many frameworks have only been stubbed out so that projects will compile and run. We're adding support for missing pieces with every release, however, so you should update frequently.

Generally, you can see what's supported and not supported by the bridge in the Visual Studio debug console. When missing or stubbed APIs are called, you'll get a message with details. We're also working on tools that will make browsing the API surface area easier.

If you find missing APIs, you should definitely [file an issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/WinObjC/issues) on Github, as it's the best way to get in touch with our team and directly affects our development roadmap.

Thanks for checking out the project!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've seen this tool https://github.com/fdierick/WinObjC-Check that should do the work (in theory) to tell what is supported and what is not. But unfortunately it doesnt work with my xcodeproj file (filed an issue about this). Maybe it can help you to build your own tool to check frameworks compliancy.